# get a subset data frame of a single row

Tags: r

I have a data frame with unique row names. I want to create a subset data frame with single row based on the the row names. When  I am using `data[rownames(data)==name, ]` I am not getting a data frame instead getting a value vector. The program is to filter data based on row names and create new data frames.

Comment: It sounds like you are on the right track, please include a [minimal reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) example for more help

Answer (score 7):

We need `drop = FALSE` as by default, the `[` have `drop = TRUE`.  So, if there is a single row, then it gets converted to lower dimension i.e. a `vector`.

```
data[rownames(data)==name, , drop = FALSE ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `subset`.

```
set.seed(4577)  # Make it reproducible

dat <- data.frame(A = sample(letters, 10), X = rnorm(10))
subset(dat, subset = rownames(dat) == 3)
#  A         X
#3 j 0.339270
```